# Salesforce Aura Component on main tab for record creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, address

I need to add a button on a custom object Tab so that a user can select it and create a new record.  This is not on a record page.  Can I reference the component in a VF page and override the standard new button?  I am also trying to use the SF Autocomplete for Standard Addresses lookup feature.  Will this be an issue.  I understand that the lookup feature does have limitations.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I've answered your questions, but in the future it would be better for these to be separated as they're related to two different pieces of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can override the standard 'New' button with a component as required. The details on how to do this are covering in the help documentation available here:

[Override Standard Actions with Aura Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides.htm)

If you're looking to use auto complete in that component, you can read up on the details of how to complete that here:

[lightning:inputAddress Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/documentation)